# How to delete click item from list?

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick, onitemclicklistener

I have the activity which includes ListView.

```
    ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_payment2);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            RowData rowData=(RowData) adapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on position : " + position + " and id : " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } );`
```

I get position item from the list. I won't use this position and delete click item from my list in my Adapter class. How to use example method `public void removeWithRowData(int position) {}` in Adapter class?

Comment: `adapter.removeWithRowData(position)`

Comment: When I use your code, the adapter lights up in red.